# How can i Add captcha to my Html form using Django

Tags: django, captcha

I have already made a website with Django but unable to add captcha with Django and link it with html template

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)‘s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too, despite its rather harsh title.

Comment: I have made a for using html and want to use captcha in the form using Django framework

Comment: This states what you _want_. Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a free coding service, but a platform for asking peers specific questions. So, what have you tried, what have you researched and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

As the others stated, I don't know what you tried so far, but there are some packages already implemented for a captcha with django.

Follow the link below and choose a package which suits your needs. If there's a problem with one of the packages you can't solve after you read the documentation, you can come back here and ask again.

[Django captcha packages.](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/captcha/)